# Is the x in "for x in dictionary" loop a global variable?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm making a simple program as a practice in Python [3.9] (Code below).

PyCharm is showing a warning "Warning: Shadows name 'subject' from outer scope" when I define the for loop variable as `subject` in (in printing grades section).

Complete code:

```py
class Student:

    grades = {}

    def __init__(self, name=""):
        self.name = name

    def get_average(self):
        total = 0
        for subject in self.grades:
            total += self.grades[subject]

        return total / len(self.grades.keys())

    def set_grade(self, subject, score):

        subject = subject.lower()

        if not isinstance(score, int):
            return None

        self.grades[subject] = int(score)

        return self.grades[subject]

    def get_grade(self, subject):
        return self.grades.get(subject)

    def get_subjects(self):
        return list(self.grades.keys())


student = Student("My Name")
student.set_grade("Mathematics", 98)
student.set_grade("english", 95)
student.set_grade("ScieNce", 93)
    
print("Name: " + student.name)
    
print("Subjects: " + str(student.get_subjects()))
    
print("Grades:")
for subject in student.get_subjects():
    print(str(subject), student.get_grade(subject))

print("Average: " + str(student.get_average()))
```

Question:
Is the `subject` in

```
for subject in student.get_subjects():
    print(str(subject), student.get_grade(subject))
```

a global variable?

If no, then why is PyCharm showing me that error and how can I improve my code for it to not show?

<s>Note: Assume the code inside the class has proper indentation. Code got reformatted when pasting code.</s>

Comment: Could you correct the indentation?

Comment: @Kimley I've edited the code in your question - I've added missing indention where I think it is necessary. Can you confirm that it is correct?

Comment: Note that it's just a *warning*. As long as you don't need access to the global variable `subject` inside the method, there is no problem. This is just static scoping working the way it is intended.

Comment: `for subject in student.get_subjects()` creates a global variable `student`, check by `globals()`. Now when you are again defining `students` in the class it is warning you that you might want to use the global variable by declaring it global, since in python variable modification is not global by default

Comment: thanks @PaulM. yes it is correct

Answer (score 0):

Your code is right and `subject` is a local variable, but pyCharm analyze whole page - so you have such warning. You can change variable name

```
for sub in student.get_subjects():
    print(str(sub), student.get_grade(sub))
```

Or you can create file named `student` and there put your Student code

```
from student import Student


student = Student("Kimley Rafallo")
student.set_grade("Mathematics", 98)
student.set_grade("english", 95)
student.set_grade("ScieNce", 93)

print("Name: " + student.name)

print("Subjects: " + str(student.get_subjects()))

print("Grades:")
for sub in student.get_subjects():
    print(str(sub), student.get_grade(sub))

print("Average: " + str(student.get_average()))
```

Comment: I see. Thank you for that.

Comment: @Kimley mark answer as useful - if you can)

Answer (score 0):

Python does not have [block scope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_(computer_science)#Block_scope), so a variable like `subject` in the loop `for subject in student.get_subjects():` belongs to whichever module or function encloses the loop. In this case, your loop is in the module's global scope so `subject` becomes a global variable.

I would suggest solving this by putting your program's logic into a `main` function, so that any variables it uses are local to that function, instead of global.

```py
def main():
    student = Student("Kimley Rafallo")
    student.set_grade("Mathematics", 98)
    student.set_grade("english", 95)
    student.set_grade("ScieNce", 93)
    
    print("Name: " + student.name)
    
    print("Subjects: " + str(student.get_subjects()))
    
    print("Grades:")
    for subject in student.get_subjects():
        print(str(subject), student.get_grade(subject))
    
    print("Average: " + str(student.get_average()))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```